# Why don't my masters match their colors appropriately?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> Gathered together as five to form one, I protect you from destruction,
> On mystical energy I'll fire my gun, the ancestors oversaw my construction.
>
> Led by a group of outsiders, they are new to this quest.
> I look to these as providers, from their hearts I am blessed.
>
> On wings of steel I'll travel across stars, seeking justice and peace for all.
> Now see there is no bond greater than ours, hear my mighty and my great call.

Who or what am I and what phrase is used to summon me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you

> Beast King GoLion? Or the American version, Voltron, Defender of the Universe?

Gathered together as five to form one, I protect you from destruction,

> GoLion/Voltron was a beast separated into 5 lion robots, but put together forms a powerful being

On mystical energy I'll fire my gun, the ancestors oversaw my construction.

> In the series, GoLion/Voltron was created long ago on a faraway planet (and has guns)

Led by a group of outsiders, they are new to this quest.

> A team of five humans control the 5 lion robot pieces.

I look to these as providers, from their hearts I am blessed.

> Put together, they control GoLion/Voltron.

On wings of steel I'll travel across stars, seeking justice and peace for all.

> It's a mechanical lion robot that flies through space against the evil Emperor's forces?

Now see there is no bond greater than ours, hear my mighty and my great call.

> It's the most powerful robot in that universe, and lions often roar.

The secret clues:

> It must be really frustrating that the colours of the humans' shirts don't match the robots they control. Also, the acrostic spells GOLION (the original Japanese anime of the American Voltron). Could the summoning song be the opening theme, "Tatakae! GoLion"? It could also be the phrase that combines them, "GoLion, gatai!".

Comment: Sort of? Specifically, I was thinking of a more western (American) version, though I think this would still be technically correct. My reasoning on this is I don't like putting the answer I'm looking for in the acrostic itself.

Comment: How does this look? I figured as much, you're usually never so direct with the acrostic.

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Leeloo from the fifth element?

Gathered together as five to form one, I protect you from destruction,

> Gathering the 5 elements prevents the earths destruction

On mystical energy I'll fire my gun, the ancestors oversaw my construction.

> An Egyptian temple turns into a weapon to kill the planet trying to kill earth

Led by a group of outsiders, they are new to this quest.
I look to these as providers, from their hearts I am blessed.

> A group of random strangers help her to get to the temple. The two main ones had nothing to do with this quest until Leeloo dropped into their laps

On wings of steel I'll travel across stars, seeking justice and peace for all.

> Leeloo arives on a ship from another planet

Now see there is no bond greater than ours, hear my mighty and my great call.

> It is her love for Bruce Willis that makes her overcome her feelings that humanity is unworthy of saving, then the firing of the weapon is a sort of scream from her.

Comment: Very interesting take to this puzzle. This isn't the answer I was looking for, but not a bad guess.